# Matplotlib vs Tkinter: Memory leak using FigureCanvasTkAgg

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter, memory-leaks

I've got a memory leak problem using matplotlib and Tkinter in the script below. Shortly, this script produces matplotlib figures containing arrows, then cleans eventually older figures and embeds these figures in canvas of Tkinter frame.

The problem is that the cleaning step doesn't work and memory used increases indefinitly when refreshing figure. It seems that figures are not destroyed when using FigureCanvasTkAgg but are destroyed if they are not embedded in canvas.

Is it a Mpl/Tk internal problem or is there a way to resolve this problem?

Here is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Tkagg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from Tkinter import *
import gc
import resource
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class Data(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_fig = []
        self.list_list = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
        self.list_wid = []

def Clean_Canvas(Test,frame):
    """ clean content of each canvas
    generated in print_figure """
    # try to eliminate each canevas contained in frame
    for i in Test.list_wid:
        i.grid_forget()
        i.destroy()
        del i
    # try to eliminate each figure in list_fig_g
    for j,i in enumerate(Test.list_fig):
        plt.close(i)
        i.clf()
        i.clear()
    Test.list_fig = []
    # get canvas ids of Tk frame
    Test.list_wid = frame.winfo_children()
    # try to eliminate nonref objects
    gc.collect()

def Figure_Maker(Test):
    """ generates 3 arrows in 4 matplotlib
    figures from list_list """
    compteur = 0
    for n,element in enumerate(Test.list_list):
        fig1 = Figure(figsize=(1,1))
        ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal',ylim=[-1,2],xlim=[-1,2])
        # drows arrows for each element in each element of list_list_g
        for k in Test.list_list[n]:
            ax1.add_patch(
                patches.Arrow(
                    0,            # x
                    -0,            # y
                    k,            # dx
                    0,            # dy
                    width=1,
                    facecolor="red",
                )
            )
        Test.list_fig.append(fig1)

def Print_Figures(Test,frame):
    """ print each plot of arrows in
    each canevas of frame"""
    compteur = 0
    # embed mpl figures in canvas
    for i in Test.list_fig:
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(i, master=frame)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=compteur,column=1)
        compteur += 1
    # get ids of each canevas to eliminates them when refreshing (in Clean_figure)
    Test.list_wid = frame.winfo_children()

def Launcher(Test,frame):
    print 'Memory usage: %s (kb)' % resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss,
    Clean_Canvas(Test,frame)
    Figure_Maker(Test)
    Print_Figures(Test,frame)
    print 'Memory usage: %s (kb)' % resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss

# main Tk
Test_g = Data()
root = Tk()
root.wm_title("mem_test")
root.configure(background="#454545")
root.winfo_toplevel()
##### entete context
Entete5 = Label(root,text="plots", bg="#454545", width=20, height=1, bd=5, fg="white").grid(row=0,column=1)
############# déclaration des scrolling bar (stickyN+S = barre et non pas des fleches)
scrollbary = Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL,bg="#454545")
scrollbary.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky=N+S, rowspan=14)
#scrollbary.rowconfigure(0, weight=4)
scrollbarx = Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL,bg="#454545")
scrollbarx.grid(row=15,column=1, sticky=E+W)
############ creation d'un canvas qui va accueillir ma frame_g
fond = Canvas(root,yscrollcommand=scrollbary.set,xscrollcommand=scrollbarx.set, width=800, height=200,bg="white")
fond.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=14, sticky=N+S+E+W)
############ Mouswheel
root.bind('<4>', lambda event : fond.yview('scroll', -1, 'units'))
root.bind('<5>', lambda event : fond.yview('scroll', 1, 'units'))
############ attacheleent des scrollbar sur le canvas
scrollbary.config(command=fond.yview)
scrollbarx.config(command=fond.xview)
########### attachement du fond sur un frame_g
frame_g = Frame(fond,width=80, height=10)
frame_g.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+E+W+S)
######### empecher le canvas de se resizer
fond.create_window(0, 0,  window=frame_g)
frame_g.update_idletasks()
fond.config(scrollregion=fond.bbox("all"))
list_wid = frame_g.winfo_children()
###### label des annotations
root.columnconfigure(2, pad=10)

######bouton selkection
Load = Button (root, text = "Load selection", command = lambda : Launcher(Test_g,frame_g), anchor=N)
Load.grid(row=7,column=4,sticky=N+E+W+S)
Load.config( height = 1, width = 11 )
root.mainloop()
```

And here is memory used for each refresh:

```
Memory usage: 39832 (kb) Memory usage: 45376 (kb)
Memory usage: 46168 (kb) Memory usage: 46960 (kb)
Memory usage: 47224 (kb) Memory usage: 47752 (kb)
Memory usage: 47752 (kb) Memory usage: 48544 (kb)
Memory usage: 48544 (kb) Memory usage: 48808 (kb)
Memory usage: 48808 (kb) Memory usage: 49072 (kb)
Memory usage: 49072 (kb) Memory usage: 49336 (kb)
Memory usage: 49336 (kb) Memory usage: 49864 (kb)
Memory usage: 49864 (kb) Memory usage: 50128 (kb)
Memory usage: 50128 (kb) Memory usage: 50392 (kb)
Memory usage: 50392 (kb) Memory usage: 50656 (kb)
```

(Python 2.7, MPL 1.1.1, Ubuntu 12.04)

Thank you,

PiSiGa

Comment: Try not importing pyplot at all.  Explictily calling `gc.collect()` _may_ help.  The extensive use of globals makes this a bit hard to track through (maybe bundle those lists up in a single class?).  If all else fails, looking at `sys.getfercount` on your objects can very illuminating

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Not importing pyplot doesn't change anything and gc.collect neither.
Using sys.getrefcount, it seems that the frame keeps references of anteriors canvas/figures, it increases linearly :  3,11,19,27,35,43...
Same thing for root: 16,32,48,64...
I suppose that it means that deletion of Canvas/figures is not efficient. What could I do to erase these objects properly to clean references of frame?
Here is a version with a class for lists.

Comment: MPL 1.1.1 is quite old (5 years!). There have been many improvements since then that improves memory usage and eliminates leaks.

Comment: I updated MPL to 2.1.0 but the leak is still there...